# Why does /*comment*/ inserted randomly inside C code works in some places only,not everywhere?

Tags: c, comments

Isn't everything between and including `/*` and `*/` ignored by the compiler?Isn't it supposed to be so everywhere in a C program, ignored as if it doesn't exist?Why then in my program it works in the most unlikely places,but fails in other places?What is the rule for commenting and what is the reason behind the observation about comments in my following ?program?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main(void)
{
char str1/*works*/[90];  //comment works
FILE *fp=fopen("D:\\source.txt","r");
if(fp==NULL){p/*Fails*/rintf("ERROR");return 0;}  //comment fails
while(fgets(str1,8/*Fails*/9,fp)!=NULL)  //comment fails
{
    if(strstr(str1,"999.999")==/*Works*/NULL)  //comment works
    printf("%s",str1);
}
fclose/*Works*/(fp);  //comment works

}
```

Comment: Short answer: No, not everywhere, and when you take a compiler course the you'll understand why.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It only works in places where you could have inserted whitespace (blanks, tabs, linebreaks).

Comment: That's a fine concise answer that tells all I wanted to know.

Answer (score 6):

A comment is treated like whitespace by the parser. So when you put it between `8` and `9`, you no longer have one number, you have two numbers separated by a space.

Comment: Wouldn't the pre-processor first strip the comments before it goes to the parser - if that's the case, then parser should be see printf

Comment: @user93353 When it strips the comment it replaces it with a space.

Comment: I took the above program & first pre-processed it with the MS pre-processor. The output of the pre-processor compiled fine - though the original itself didn't compile/

Comment: @user93353 Obviously the compiler is not using that preprocessor to remove comments.

Answer (score 2):

C99 says that there is a translation phase which happens prior to the preprocessing. In translation phase3, comments are replaced by space. So obviously your program won't compile.
This is given in Section 6.10 of C99.

```
char str1 [90];
```

is valid (space between `str1` and `[`). Hence it compiles.

However

```
p rintf("ERROR");
```

isn't valid. Hence it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(fp==NULL){p/*Fails*/rintf("ERROR");return 0;}  //comment fails
```

Here compiler is treating your code as /p rintf/ due to the fact that comment appears to be a whiltespace so this is the reason your comment fails.

```
while(fgets(str1,8/*Fails*/9,fp)!=NULL)  //comment fails
```

Again same mistake, /8 9/ is not valid as interpreted by compiler.